# fail to compile with error "main not found in -lCGAL", symlinks not the issue

Tags: unix, build, linker, shared-libraries

I am trying to build some software (namely the python module graph-tool, http://projects.skewed.de/graph-tool/) on a network I don't have root access to.  So, I installed all of the dependencies myself on the local disk using --prefix and --with-include flags and the CPPFLAGS and LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variables.

Having done that, I'm getting a weird error about not finding one of my dependencies (namely, CGAL: http://www.cgal.org/).

The configure script says `checking for main in -lCGAL... no` and the makefile, after printing an enormous number of compiler warnings, fails with `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCGAL`

Presumably, this means that it simply can't find the installed library.  Pretty much all of the other instances where this happens, google reveals that they didn't have the symbolic link to the library correctly set.  It appears to be correctly set here:

```
truffles:rlaplant[147] echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/local_mount/space/truffles/1/users/rlaplant/graphtool/parts/lib:/local_mount/space/truffles/1/users/rlaplant/graphtool/parts/
truffles:rlaplant[160] file parts/lib/libCGAL.so
parts/lib/libCGAL.so: symbolic link to `libCGAL.so.10'
```

I can't really figure out what's wrong.  Maybe there is a problem with the way I am using LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out what my problem was.

Despite libCGAL.so being a dynamically linked library, what the compile script is actually doing is treating it as though its a static library.  I didn't know it was able to do this, I thought that if it were a statically linked library it couldn't also be dynamically linked and vice versa (and I think this is typically true in practice).

What I did here was set LIBRARY_PATH which looks for static libraries, rather than LD_LIBRARY_PATH which looks for dynamically linked libraries at run/link time.  I believe that this distinction would be moot if the configure script had been better written to take into account what I am trying to do here with the funny prefixes, because then it would be able to just use the -L flag and as far as I can tell this works for both static and dynamic linking, but the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable doesn't (but that may not be true).